# What would be the dose rate of 109 grams of uranium per day/year?

Tags: radiation, biophysics, medical-physics

I know that with a Pancake probe that can read alpha you can get up to 30K CPM on a small plate. I ordered a 6" red plate off ebay and measured outside the box when it came in. It registered around 200 CPM on a CDV-700 with the beta shield open set against the box with the plate in it.

I did some calculations and came up with a rough estimate of 109 grams of uranium inside the glaze on the plate. I don't know if it is natural uranium or DU as they were manufactured using both and I lack the proper tools to find out.

Edited question:
What would be the estimated dose rate of 109 grams of uranium per day/year?

Thank you for your time and help.

Here is a picture for reference:
[image: CPM of Feistaware plate outside of box]

Comment: 1) [Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/994/is-red-fiestaware-radioactive). 2) XKCD [Radiation Chart](http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/03/19/radiation-chart/)

Comment: Wait - you think betas and alphas are getting through the box? What does your meter read away from the box?

Comment: AFAIK, "dangerous" isn't something quantifiable by physicists. You could ask whether this is a reasonable value from the source given its history, or something along those lines.

Comment: Indeed, if you are asking for a cancer risk given the radiation you've already measured, that is definitely biology, not physics.

Comment: The field of radiation safety is one where the doctors often call on physicists for advice (calculating exposure, designing does schedules and delivery programs). I've helped one of my students secure a position as a junior radiation physicist at Mayo. Depending on how Caspian would like to slant this I think it can be on-topic (focus on the dose) or off (focus on the health effects).

Comment: That said, look at the uranium decay chains. Most of the energy is in alphas and betas. Short penetration depths. Most of the photons are pretty low energy, too. I leave my orange salt-shaker (reads tens of counts per second at the top surface on our classroom demonstration counter) in a cardboard box on the other side of my office and don't worry about it because I'm surely getting more dose from the K-40 in the cinder-block walls.

Comment: Jon Custer:Not much. Alphas, no, They are stopped by the box and the CDV-700 is blind to them anyway. Betas, most likely penetrating the box. Gamma is present but at low levels compared to beta. Uranium 238 -> Thorium 234 is where the Alpha comes from. Thorium -> Protactinium 234m is where most of the beta is coming from. From what I have researched anyway.

As far as this being categorized incorrectly, um, sorry? I thought that this information would be in the physics category as the question is related to radiation, so i decided to seek info from physicists. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: dmckee: Dosage, I definitely didn't get the plate to eat off of, which is where I think the confusion is coming from. I am interested in learning more about Nuclear Physics so I got a Geiger counter to go look for rocks and discover more about my environment. I heard about Fiesta ware sitting in thrift stores and I know that there are people who sell parts of broken plates as check sources, but if you break it you risk the glaze turning to dust. So, I bought a whole plate. The more I read the more the water seemed to mud up. I was just looking for some clarity from others who know.

Comment: And I found this link on the decay chains, thank you for that, dmckee.

http://www.theiet.org/factfiles/energy/uranium238-page.cfm?type=pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about health risks from radiation not physics

Comment: Well, again, sorry for asking here. I would delete the question but it won't let me and I don't see a way that I can close it myself.

Comment: It won't let you delete it because the question has an accepted answer. In principle you could un-accpet nukular's answer and then delete the question, or you could just leave it. It's not closed yet and one closed question is no big deal. Even better, if you wanted you could edit the question to focus much more clearly on the issue of determining dose and perhaps the user will be more accepting. (Note that closed question can be re-opened by the same process that lets them get closed in the first place, and that questions edited after being closed are automatically submitted for review.)

Comment: Edited question, hopefully it is more on topic with Physics. Thank you, dmckee.

Comment: First go back and redo your calculations. 780 grams of uranium? Seriously?

Comment: Edited to 109 grams.

Comment: Once again - seriously? 100 grams on a 6" plate? Please provide your calculations. http://chemistry.about.com/od/nuclearchemistry/fl/How-Radioactive-Is-Fiesta-Ware.htm suggests about 4.5 g although they don't specify plate size.

Comment: Ok, I admit that math is not my strong suit, but I am trying. 
A 6” plate has radius of 3”. 

9 π in2 = 28.27 in squared. X2 because it is glazed on both sides = 56.54in2

X 2mm as the glaze is 2mm thick from what I read = 4.45in3

Rounding up to 4.5in3, 14% of that = 0.63in3

0.63in3 = 197 grams of uranium.

Last time I rounded the squared inches which came out to a more conservative estimate of 109. So, I tried.

I am going to stop now, this is wearing my patience for social cooperation thin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely not dangerous, especially sitting in your garage. A count rate reading from a GM tube tells you very little. Not only is there no information about the energy of the radiation being recorded, you make no mention of the distance your probe was from the source during the time of the reading. You also failed to specify a background count rate. A scintillation detector or even an ionization chamber would be more apt to tell you what you're dealing with (likely trace uranium).

If you don't feel safe eating off of it don't, but it won't pose a threat to your health by owning it. The total amount of activity in the entire plate is likely on the order of a microcurie or much less.

A good reference on the subject would be G. Knoll's "Radiation Detection and Measurement"

Answer (score 0):

Even in your "reference article" it it said: "The actual amount of radioactivity is extremely low -less than the normal background radiation you get from rocks and stuff" and "if in fact it's a problem, is that uranium is a heavy metal, as is lead [;]both could leach into food, particularly if it's acidic."
So if you really wonder the risk for your health, don't measure it with a radiometer ! (any kind of heavy metal, in particular any isotope of uranium, is then the issue, while only some kind is radioactive).

Further, in physics as in biology, quantities is a key thing. If you extract 100% of the paint of a plate in order to eat it all, how much nanograms of heavy metal it makes ? which proportion would be absorbed by your intestine ? Compare to the recommendation thresholds.
Then, in physics as in biology, comparisons and proportion is also a key thing. Among all the risks you have around you, even just those related to food and eating, what would be the order of importance of this one in the ordered list ? When was your fridge disinfected for the last time ? How fresh and isolated was the food ? How rinsed were the dishes ? (and are you sure of the metal of the spoon ? or the air of the room ?). 
In term of food-related risk it seems that many fantasy or true but very small things are in focus, while people seems to have totally forgotten that our very first historical enemy are bacteria (more bleach everywhere, please. And avoiding uncooked and cooked chicken sharing a same plate in a row is probably way more important than the paint below).